# jqGrid TreeGrid find parent id of a node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to get parentId of a row in jqGrid tree. below is the sample code

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $this = $(this);

    var localData = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);

    var parentNode = $this.jqGrid("getNodeParent", localData);
}
```

I get parentNode as Object but if I try to get `alert(parentNode.id)`, it returns null..

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: It should be  alert(parentNode.attr('id')) or  alert(parentNode[0].id) because parentNode is a jQuery object

Comment: thanks for your response. alert(parentNode.attr('id')) or alert(parentNode[0].id) giving error "cannot find id of undefined"... alert(parentNode) returns :  [object object]

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitive maybe ?

```
alert(parentNode.ID)
```

I presume you are using a older version of jqgrid (3.7) because ("getNodeParent") does no longer work as of version 3.7.x ( http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid ). 
You can try and use :

`var record = $(”#grid_id”).getRowData(rowid);
console.log(record.ID)`

instead if you are using a newer version of jqgrid.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am using latest version of jqgrid( 4.x.) and both the approaches to get the id work (i.e. via getNodeParent or getRowData as you suggested) and console.log(record.ID) also works fine, however I want to get Id of the parent row.. how would I do that ?

Comment: I don't know if I follow. But if you now the rowid and the grid why not use `$("#grid_id").find('#'+record);`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need just use `parent` property of `localData`: `localData.parent`. It's the `id` of the parent node. By the way the `id` of the node will be typically saved in `_id_` property (so `localData._id_` is the same as `rowid` and `dataOfParentNode._id_` is the same as `localData.parent`). To get full data of the parent node you can use `getLocalRow` instead of `getNodeParent`:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        localData = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
        dataOfParentNode = $this.jqGrid("getLocalRow", localData.parent);
    ...
    return true;
}
```